# Usage of "del mismo al ser"

Tags: traducción, expresiones, significado

I seem to not be able to work though the meaning of *del mismo al ser*.  I'm seeing this in the context of a description of two people's roles in developing a popular videogame.  Despite the contributions of one person, the other is still considered the *father* of the project and the owner of the company.

Is *del mismo al ser* a typical way of saying something?  While I may be getting the underlying idea that is being expressed, I'm frustrated that I can't reconcile it with something in English.  Any clarification will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Here is the contextual sentence:

> El diseñador Toru Iwatani fue el desarrollador del juego con un concepto muy sencillo que alcanzaba 256 niveles, pero Nakamura es considerado el padre **del mismo al ser** el dueño de la compañía.

I suppose seeing the al ser is throwing me off the most.

Comment: For more accurate answers, I recommend you to give some more context, and even the text that is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer**: please give some more context. This answer could be rendered completely useless after you do, but it is also quite difficult to try to explain something with that little understanding of what is giving you trouble.

[Mismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=POzAgFS) is an adejetive that means "the same as", but can be used as a pronoun would.

> Diego es el creador de la empresa y presidente de la *misma* (empresa)  <sub>Diego is the founder of the company and CEO of *it*</sub>

That construction "al ser" is just explaining something. It is an equivalent of for example "ya que es" or "dado que". Best way I can think to translate it in English would be "Since he/she/it is ...", meaning "given the fact that ...".

So I believe (based on what currently your question explains) that you might have encountered some text like:

> Alice y Bob han trabajado juntos desarrollando el videojuego XYZ. Alice ha sido una gran contribuidora, pero Bob es considerado el padre **del mismo al ser** el dueño de la empresa.

So there "mismo" refers to the project or videogame.

> Alice ha sido una gran contribuidora [al proyecto del videojuego], pero Bob es considerado el padre **del mismo [del proyecto del videojuego] al ser** [Bob] el dueño de la empresa.

Which could be translated as

> Alice and Bob worked together developing the videogame XYZ. Alice has been a great contributor, but Bob is considered the father of the project **since he [Bob] is** the owner of the company.

I hope this helps. Probably my example is nothing like you really encountered, but it might help you to understand the usage of the expression.

Comment: Here is the contextual sentence.

**El diseñador Toru Iwatani fue el desarrollador del juego con un concepto muy sencillo que alcanzaba 256 niveles, pero Nakamura es considerado el padre del mismo al ser el dueño de la compañía.**

I suppose seeing the **al ser** is throwing me off the most.

Comment: @Blamettu, Then I guess I wasn't that far off. Just change Alice and Bob for Iwatani and Nakamura. Nakaura is considered the father of the creation (the videogame) **since** he was/is the owner of the company.

Comment: To be sure, **del mismo** is acting as the pronoun for the juego in question.  It looks as though **ser** in this context is the noun form wherein **a+el ser** becomes **al ser**.  Is this correct?


I just read your explanation of **al ser** again.

Comment: What I'm getting is that **al ser** is a construction that doesn't have a direct translation to English.

Comment: @Blamettu: "**del mismo** is acting as the pronoun for the juego in question": Correct. "Al ser" means something like "Since [he] is...", which in this contexts stands for "given the fact that...".

Answer (score 0):

> Nakamura es considerado el padre del mismo al ser el dueño de la compañía.

*Del mismo* refers back to whatever was being talked about earlier in the paragraph, in this case, the game.

*Al ser* might be easier to understand if we replace it with *por ser*, and put an optional comma in front:

> Nakamura es considerado el padre del juego, por ser el dueño de la compañía.

Technically, "al ser" means "upon being," and "por ser" means "by being," or "because of "being."  A more natural way of expressing the sentence in English would be

> Nakamura, in his role as the owner of the company, is considered the father of the game.